# Clear value after button clicked

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, lightning-inputfield

I have three different lighting component:

1. Lightning input rich text
2. Lightning input search
3. Lightning input file
4. Lightning datatable

After a button is clicked I want to delete all the values the user inputted the problem is that after redaing how to delete the inputs it is not working. Inside of my handleButtonAction I have this:

```
if(result == 'success'){
            this.filesData = [];
            this.showToast('Success', 'success', 'Notificación enviada a todos los miembros.');
            
            this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input').forEach(element => {
                element.value ='';
            })
            this.template.querySelector('lightning-input-rich-text').forEach(element => {
                element.value = '';
            })
            let deselectedRecs = this.selectedRowsRows
             .filter(x => !selRows.includes(x))
             .concat(selRows.filter(x => !this.selectedRows.includes(x)));

        }else{
            this.showToast('Error', 'error', result);
        }
```

It is not working with none of them. Could anybody help me?
Thanks

For my datatable I want to unchecked rows that area records from an object:
[image]

Comment: Use '' rather than null

Comment: @Elijah it only works for the lightning-input but not for the lightning-input-rich-text nor the datatable. Can you put an example for this two cases?

Comment: Using "" should work on input , rich text and file fields. Share what you want to clear from datatable

Comment: @Elijah I updated what I need to do